# Countdown Timer in Javascript won't run in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, timer, countdown

I wrote this countdown timer, and it works in everything but IE. I get the restricted website from running scripts. But when I click that it is ok , the script doesn't run.

Is there a proper way to set up a javascript script to run after the pause for user ok?
Or is there a way to write it so it works for IE also.

I am not sending anything via innerHTML as code just numbers so I don't see that as the problem, and I rewrote it using the jQuery .html() function with the same results...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JQuery Countdowwn Timer</title>
<style type="text/css">
span#days {   font-size:20px;
                color:#900;
                  font-weight:900;

}
span#hours {   font-size:20px;
                color:#903;
                font-weight:900;
}
span#min {   font-size:20px;
                color:#906;
                font-weight:900;
}
span#sec {   font-size:20px;
                color:#909;
                font-weight:900;
}
span#date {font-size:22px;
font-weight:900;
                color:#900;


}

span#mar {font-size:22px;
font-weight:900;
color:#03F;}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function theTimer(){

var putday=document.getElementById("days");
var puthour=document.getElementById("hours");
var putmin =document.getElementById("min");
var putsec=document.getElementById("sec");

var marathon=new Date(2012,3,22,10,0,0,0);
var marathonCount=marathon.getTime();
var nowish=Date.now();
var dif=marathonCount-nowish;

var days=Math.floor(dif/(24*60*60*1000));
dif=dif-days*(24*60*60*1000);
var hours=Math.floor(dif/(60*60*1000)); 
dif=dif-hours*(60*60*1000);
var minutes=Math.floor(dif/(60*1000));
dif=dif-minutes*(60*1000);
var seconds=Math.floor(dif/1000);

putday.innerHTML="this stuffF"; 
putday.innerHTML=days;
puthour.innerHTML=hours;
putmin.innerHTML=minutes;
putsec.innerHTML=seconds;

var counter = setTimeout("theTimer()", 1000) };
</script>
</head>

<body onload="theTimer()">
<a href ="" style="text-decoration:none">
<center>
<p id="marathon">There are <span id="days"></span> days, <span id="hours"></span> hours, <span id="min"></span> minutes, and <span id="sec"></span> seconds left </p>
</center>
<center>
<p id="marathon">till the beginning of the Next <span id="mar">Marathon</span> on <span id="date">April 22, 2012.</span></p>
</center>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just a thought... http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/

Comment: Are you running this local on your machine? You might have to "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer": Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> scroll down to 'Security'

Comment: I even uploaded it to my server because I heard that IE wouldn't allow local html calls. Same result. ..

Comment: Works fine for me in IE9. Which version are you trying with?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Naren for your comment about IE9 working.

I tracked it down to using `Date.now()`

That doesn't work in IE8 (which is one of the trial computer browsers I used) and probably earlier.

If I just do

```
new Date().getTime();
```

IE8 handles that.